# PHP session_id() changes after POST

Tags: php, session

I have an odd situation that's come up on my production server. However, it's not a problem in my local development environment. Here's a test script with which I can replicate the problem:

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['test'] = 'test';

echo 'session_id(): '.session_id();

session_write_close();

?>

<form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Post to self" />
</form>
```

If I load this page in my browser, and refresh the page (CTRL+R), I'm shown the same `session_id()` value each time.

However, if I then click the submit button, I get two different outcomes:

- Development: the same `session_id()` value (the expected outcome).
- Production: a **different** `session_id()` value.

Further, on the production server, if I then reload the page again I get the **original** `session_id()` value back.

How do I get the production server to persist the `session_id()` value? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

**Details From Comment:**
In the basic example I posted, it's like this:

```
array(5) { 
         ["lifetime"]=> int(0) 
         ["path"]=> string(1) "/" 
         ["domain"]=> string(0) "" 
         ["secure"]=> bool(false) 
         ["httponly"]=> bool(false) 
         }
```

In the actual production code it's like this:

```
array(5) { 
         ["lifetime"]=> int(0) 
         ["path"]=> string(1) "/" 
         ["domain"]=> string(0) "" 
         ["secure"]=> bool(true) 
         ["httponly"]=> bool(true) 
         }
```

(I'm using HTTPS in production).

Comment: read this problem and answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180559/should-i-regenerate-session-id-on-every-page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180559/should-i-regenerate-session-id-on-every-page)

Comment: `var_dump(session_get_cookie_params())`?

Comment: @Federico - In the basic example I posted, it's like this:

`array(5) { ["lifetime"]=> int(0) ["path"]=> string(1) "/" ["domain"]=> string(0) "" ["secure"]=> bool(false) ["httponly"]=> bool(false) }`

In the actual production code it's like this:

`array(5) { ["lifetime"]=> int(0) ["path"]=> string(1) "/" ["domain"]=> string(0) "" ["secure"]=> bool(true) ["httponly"]=> bool(true) }`

(I'm using HTTPS in production).

Comment: I have updated your question with your comment, @user4024288 . If possible try to update your question with code as code is not very readable in comments. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everyone; wild goose chase. On my host's advice, I had run EasyApache to upgrade the server to PHP to v5.5. In doing so the PHP handler had inadvertently been switched to something other than SuPHP, and was therefore having read permissions issues on the session files in `/tmp`. As a result, PHP was continually generating new session files.

Edit: I should also note that `is_writable(session_save_path())` was returning **true**, which is what misled my understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Safest way is to tell PHP to use cookies. Requires users to allow session coookies.

```
session_name(SESSION_NAME);

// PHP 5.2+ Prevent x-domain cookie sess theft. Dont let Client scripts see cookie
$HTTPONLY = 1; // 0 or 1;

if (function_exists('session_set_cookie_params')) 
{
    session_set_cookie_params(3600, '/', '.domain.com', 0, $HTTPONLY);
} elseif (function_exists('ini_set')) 
{
    ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 3600);
    ini_set('session.cookie_path', '/');
    ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.domain.com');

    ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', $HTTPONLY);
}
```

You could also keeping passing the SESSION_ID through a form variable but that is not as safe.

Comment: Note you need to do the above before 
 session_start();

Comment: Also, if your development host is "localhost" or an IP address this won't work on it. If your using a sub-domain or domain or even localhost.com it will work./

Comment: I appreciate your feedback @Baine, though I'm thinking this is more of a configuration issue than a code issue. The same example works in multiple other environments I've tried it in. So I'm wondering whether there's something up in cPanel/WHM (which this server runs on), or problems with the session path (which is `/tmp` FWIW) - although PHP tells me this path is writable.

Comment: Ini_set('session.use_cookies')

Comment: Yes, I'm using that, plus: `session.use_only_cookies`, `session.cookie_httponly`, and `session.cookie_secure`.

Comment: The only other thing I can think would cause your problem is, Ifyour using SSL, or https, the cookies will not transfer across non SSL if you have the secure only flag set.

Answer (score -1):

//    session_regenerate_id()

```
session_start();

    if(isset($_POST)){
        $_SESSION['IDONE'] = session_id();
        session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['IDTWO'] = session_id();
        var_dump($_SESSION);
    }
```

Set the "name" attribute to the `<input>` tag so the `$_POST` variable will consist of a variable.

[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php)

Comment: I understand what you're suggesting, but unfortunately the session data does not persist. If I set some session variables in another script, then load this script and `var_dump($_SESSION)`, I can initially see that data but if I submit the form, then its gone.