# Is session_id() required at the top of every page?

Tags: php

I know that `session_start()` is required at the top of every page to continue a session. Is it  also required to declare the `session_id()` at the top of every page as well or does `session_start()` remember the `session_id()` for the duration of the session from the first page?

Comment: Do you need to change the default session ID? What happens when you omit session_id()?

Comment: I dont need to change it. I just want to know if the session will remember the id or if I have to set it for every page?

Comment: Then, I'll just drop a generic tip: if there's a function to do X and you don't need X, you probably don't need the function.

Comment: Let me ask this a different way. Does session_start remember the current session_id if leave the page and go to another page?

Comment: @Adam yes it remember everything that you save in your session.

Comment: @zaheer  Thanks much.

Comment: Are you interested something like this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801843/php-how-to-manage-multiple-session-in-same-browser-using-cookies

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I regenerate\_session\_id on every page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180559/should-i-regenerate-session-id-on-every-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** an update to your actual question:

page1.php:

```
<?php
    session_id('test');
    session_start();
```

page2.php

```
<?php  
session_start();
var_dump(session_id());
```

When you first open page1.php and after that page2.php the output of page2.php will be:

> string(4) "test"

Comment: I was just curious if I have the session_id function on every page. The purpose for this is I want to separate sessions for a web page being used by multiple users on the same computer, such as have two facebook accounts open at the same time on one computer

Comment: Changed my answer to some simple example.

Comment: Thank you. I will definatley remember for the future.